# Microsoft Excel 2003 | IF Statements

Tags: excel, if-statement

Firstly I'd like to say my knowledge on Excel is fairly limited, and I'm learning as I go, so feel free to input/correct on anything.

I have a set of information formated as follows:

```
0.7 9.0 598287      
0.7 10.0 598288     
0.9 36.0 9186264        
4.5 298.0 4071637       
4.3 287.0 13896286      
0.9 18.0 4011248
```

I need a to create a formula, that takes each peice of data, the first decimal number, the second, and the final string of numbers. I've created a very long - and seemingly good statement, but it doesn't do exactly as I need. My Formula, and the outputs are as follows

```
=IF(LEN(J194)=14,RIGHT(J194,6),IF(LEN(J194)=15,RIGHT(J194,6),IF(LEN(J194)=16,RIGHT(J194,6),IF(LEN(J194)=17,RIGHT(J194,7),IF(LEN(J194)=18,RIGHT(J194,8),RIGHT(J194,8))))))

   **DATA**             **OUTPUT**       **LENGTH**

0.7 9.0 598287          598287               14
0.7 10.0 598288         598288               15
0.9 36.0 9186264        186264               16
4.5 298.0 4071637       4071637              17
4.3 287.0 13896286      13896286             18
0.9 18.0 4011248        011248               16
```

The last column is the string length, as you can see - although the lengths of the strings are the same, I get a different output because the characters preceeding are shorter (1 digit,2 digit and 3 digit numbers)

What I need the formula to do, because my strings range from 14-18 characters in length, is to take the last digits no matter the overall cell length. I am also adding an E to the front of each of these numbers via =CONCATENATE - so I cannot overcount.

I'll gladly awnser any questions regarding my problem if clarifaction is needed.

Thanks for taking the time to read over my post!

Comment: It's not clear what kind of output do you expect? Can you please give couple of examples?

Comment: Sure - I need the output to be the final digits in the DATA string, so the numbers after the second decimal number. Heres an example:

Comment: 0.7 9.0 598287       ---->        598287
0.9 18.0 4011248     ---->        4011248   

and so on..

Comment: Can you just use "Text to Columns" function and split your data into columns by space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=RIGHT(J194,LEN(J194)-FIND(" ",J194,FIND(" ",J194)+1))
```

Comment: Would it be possible to semi-explain this? Or state the changes I have to make? I've never used FIND before.

Comment: Aha! eggplant_parm has used a similar trick to me... The second "Find" locates the first space, then adds one to the location. That us used as the input to the second "Find" to locate the index of the second space. This value is then subtracted from the total length to get what you're looking for. One area where caution may be needed is if there are any lines where there are more (or less) spaces in the input value as errors may occur.

Comment: Exactly... btw, I think InstrRev is a vba function, not worksheet.

Comment: Well isn't that crafty - Thanks a ton Eggplant_Parm and Richard, I've now got exactly what I need.

Thanks again, and have a great evening
-Colin

Comment: I know you have an answer that works for you, but was curious if the source of the data was imported differently whether you would need to separate the output column the way you are.